# Correct way to double the amount of Power Points necessary to manifest a power through Remote Viewing

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

[Remote Viewing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/r/remote-viewing) states that one can "attempt to manifest one power through your quasi-real viewpoint", but it also states that "all powers from your quasi-real viewpoint cost twice the usual number of power points". Does this mean that only the initial cost of the power is doubled and the power can be augmented as normal, or do you include the augmentations spent in the doubling of the power's cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You double the total cost, including augmentations. There is no division between "base cost" and "augmentation cost" - only the cost to manifest a power.

*Andreas Rönnqvist*
**Dreamscarred Press**
Author of Psionics Unleashed/Ultimate Psionics

Comment: You might want to cite your sources. (Or, y'know, supply your credentials. `:-)`)

Comment: Yeah, especially since I'm already aware of this line of rhetoric as a possibility. What I'm looking for is RAW support for why this is the case. If there is no RAW basis for this answer and you think there is any RAW basis that could answer this question, you should indicate that such is the case and that this is how you'd rule the matter.

Comment: @user3735278 It is worth noting that Andreas **wrote *Psionics Unleashed* in the first place.** If there’s nothing in the RAW to support what he says, he could very easily include it in the next errata.